# Change Recommended Resolution in Windows

Tags: display, resolution

I have an older monitor that I run in my system, and I'm able to select the correct display size in Display options, but Windows is choosing the incorrect display size for the "recommended resolution."

The reason this is an issue for me is that AMD software (and I suppose other software must) uses the "recommended" resolution as per Windows to decide the target resolution for display scaling. The effect of this is that, if I turn on display scaling, then my display gets squished to 720x350, which is a weird resolution that this display doesn't even properly support. It's also not the right aspect ratio, as this is an older 4:3 (or possibly 5:4?) size display (it's more square, not widescreen).

Is there some way I can change this behavior?

Thanks

To the comments:

Windows is clearly not getting EDID from this monitor, or it's not using it correctly because, as I said, it's choosing a resolution that is the wrong aspect ratio. Additionally, the monitor doesn't support the resolution in it's manual at all.

Ideally, I would be able to pick any resolution I want, but the native res is 1600x1200@85Hz.

Comment: The OS gets the information about the monitor from  the EDID - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data - and decides accordingly.

Comment: What is the precise resolution you want Windows to stick to by default?